# Error obtaining parameters of a structure pointer in c ++

Tags: c++

I have defined the following structure:

```
struct com_NetworkStruct 
{
    enum com_NetworkStatus status;
    char IPV4_Addr[COM_IPV4_ADDR_LENGTH];
    char IPV4_Netmask[COM_IPV4_ADDR_LENGTH];
    char IPV4_DNS1[COM_IPV4_ADDR_LENGTH];
    char IPV4_DNS2[COM_IPV4_ADDR_LENGTH];
    int IPV4_DHCP_Enabled;
    int IPV6_Supported;
    int IPV6_Enabled;
    struct com_IPv6_Data *IPV6_Address_List;
    char HW_Addr[COM_ETH_MAC_ADDR_LENGTH];
    int MTU_Size;
    int Link_Speed;
    enum com_LinkType Link_Type;
};
```

And the following method definition:

```
int foo(struct com_NetworkStruct **netinfo);
```

This is the main function and how i call the function:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    char data_aux[200];
    struct com_NetworkStruct *netinfo = NULL;

    ret = foo(&netinfo);

    memset(data_aux, 0, sizeof(data_aux));
    sprintf(data_aux, "%s", netinfo->IPV4_Addr);

    cout<<string(data_aux)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I try to read the data of the `IPV4_Addr` value since it sends me the following error:

```
Error:  #289: no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_CharT, Traits, Alloc>::basic_string [with CharT=char, Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (const char [20], char [16])
```

I already tried this, but nothing works:

```
&netinfo->IPV4_Addr
netinfo.IPV4_Addr
string(netinfo->IPV4_Addr)
```

Comment: Perhaps it's just a simplified example, but why the copy from one array to another, and then construction of a string, when you could just `cout << netinfo->IPV4_Addr`; ?

Comment: where is the definition of com_NetworkInterfaceInfo?  you provided only  com_NetworkStruct

Comment: @Alex sorry that was my mistake, edited.

Comment: @PhilM actually i want to get the content of  IPV4_Addr in a string and then print the string.

Comment: Couple of notes: First, that isn't the full error message. Second, in C++, you don't need `struct com_NetworkStruct` or `enum com_NetworkStatus` when declaring variables of those types, you can leave out `struct`/`class`/`enum`.

Comment: Please show the complete error message. I see nothing in the code shown that would cause any error involving a `char_traits`. And you don't need a conversion to `string` when passing a `char[]` to `operator<<`.

Comment: Can you edit to include a [mcve] that has the same error?

Comment: what is the line of code caused this error?

Comment: @Alex sprintf()

Comment: @NoeCano There is no way `sprintf` can cause the (partial) error text you have shown. Something else is going on. Please provide a [mcve] and the FULL error message.

Comment: @PhilM Edited with the complete error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau edited with the complete error.

Comment: @NoeCano there is no way the code shown can be causing that error message. The only `string` constructor being called in the code shown is on the `cout<<string(data_aux)<<endl;` line, and it is being passed only 1 argument, a `char[200]`, but the error is complaining about 2 arguments being passed, a `char[20]` and a `char[16]`. So, where else are you constructing a `string` object in code you have not shown? Where are you using a `char[20]` buffer? Because the code shown doesn't have a `char[20]`, it has a `char[200]`, and I assume `COM_IPV4_ADDR_LENGTH` is 16, making `IPV4_Addr` a `char[16]`

Comment: Unless you've somehow #defined `data_aux` to something else, I don't see how that call to `string`'s constructor yields that error. This is why an MCVE, that you've actually tried to compile, and then directly copy/pasted into the question, is important.